# in mysql where command not work

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

Hi when i call this query for select this work good and make output

```
select SUBSTR(img_address1,LOCATE('/',img_address2)+1,36)fROM content
```

but when i make this query this make a error

```
SELECT id from content WHERE ((SUBSTR(img_address2,LOCATE('/',img_address2)+1,5) LIKE'salam')
```

and this make error too

```
SELECT id from content WHERE ((SUBSTR(img_address2,LOCATE('/',img_address2)+1,5) = 'salam')
```

and my error is :

```
SELECT id from content WHERE ((SUBSTR(img_address2,LOCATE('/',img_address2)+1,5) = 'salam') LIMIT 0, 25
MySQL said: Documentation

 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra open bracket `(` before `SUBSTR`. Removing it will fix the error.

```
SELECT id from content WHERE (SUBSTR(img_address2,LOCATE('/',img_address2)+1,5) = 'salam') LIMIT 0, 25
```